# Conditional options for Rails methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, form-for

I want to add a class to a `form_for` method, but how would I do that?

```
<% if @plan.price == 0 %>
   <%= form_for @account, :html => { :class => 'new_account' } do |f| %>
<% else %>
   <%= form_for @account, :html => { :class => 'new_account payment-form' } do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Seems there's gotta be a more concise way to pull that off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<%= form_for @account, html: { class: "new_account #{(@plan.price == 0) ? '' : 'payment-form'}" } do |f| %>
```

Comment: There is no need for the ternary Operator, one could just do `html: { class: "new_account#{' payment-form' if @plan.price == 0}"`

Comment: I don't like this typo, I always prefer to have both true & false case and their respective outputs (even if here it's nothing, maybe tomorrow you'll want to print the class 'empty-price' for the true case)